# Dividing a large list of float and plotting

Tags: python, list, plot

I have a large list which consists of float values.

My question is how can I plot that list?

I read it should be sliced first but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Where did you read that? why should you slice your poor list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotting a list of numbers is straightforward using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
your_list = [2.3, 5.7, -1.4, 4.6, -2.9, 7.2]
plt.plot(your_list)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help and advices.